# In OpenCart, how to make customers get a discount if choose a specific payment method?

Tags: opencart, payment, discount

In OpenCart, how do you make customers receive a discount if they chose "western union" payment?

The desired effect is that the total would auto-change, once the customer clicks to select "western union" payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create an order total module that implemented this discount.  You'd check the payment type, and trigger if it was Western Union.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @bestshop24h.  If an answer is correct, you can indicate that by checking the checkmark.  If it's helpful, you can upvote it.